# windows task manager showing multiple ruby instances in Processes for a single app

Tags: ruby, windows

A ruby application is showing multiple processes in the server, though it's the same application. It's a windows server.

How can I remove all but one process for this application without manually closing them from the windows task manager.

Pleas help.

Comment: Is the app using threads ? What happens when the app itself closes ? are there processes left ? If not too much could you publish the code ?

Comment: I am using Thin. nothing happens when the app is closed, the ruby process still continues and shows in the Task Manager Processes. Yeah the code is bit lengthy one..any  specific part u wanna see?Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you're running your app (Passenger? Thin? Mongrel? mod_ruby?), this could actually be normal. As in, the app keeps a pool of processes running until they time out, each awaiting new requests, much like a dynamic php/fastcgi pool would do.

Along the same lines, and per Peter's comment, might it be using threads? If so, it could be equally normal, as in it launches some background jobs before returning and the processes remain around until those jobs are completed.

Comment: I am using Thin. nothing happens when the app is closed, the ruby process still continues and shows in the Task Manager Processes. Can I specify to stop the process in Thin configuration file?? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You'd want to double check but I seem to remember Thin staying alive. Purposely so, to avoid reinterpreting the ruby code and restarting the app when it could simply process another request.

Answer (score 0):

It is reported that thin opens multiple threads per connection over time and i suppose a thread will be a process.

Try if
`thin restart -C /etc/thin/app.yml`
helps.

See http://jordanhollinger.com/2011/04/22/how-to-use-thin-effectivly

Limitting your maximum connections, timeout to the minimum will also help.